# xlwings can not locate my file?

Tags: xlwings

I'm using python to operate a excel file.My python project is located at

```
D:\Python\Project
```

the excel file I wanna operate is located at

```
‪C:\Users\wenbo\Desktop\test.xlsx
```

Below is my code:

```
import xlwings

workbook=xlwings.Book(r"‪C:\Users\wenbo\Desktop\test.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheets['Sheet1']
sheet.cells(1, 1).value=1
```

When I run the code,there was an error:

`FileNotFoundError: No such file: '‪c:\users\wenbo\desktop\test.xlsx'`

This is not right,I'm sure test.xlsx is located on my desktop.

But when I move test.xlsx to

```
D:\Python\Project
```

the following code works fine:

```
import xlwings

workbook=xlwings.Book(r"test.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheets['Sheet1']
sheet.cells(1, 1).value=1
```

So,it seems that xlwings can only locate file in the same project folder.But I think there must be another way to locate a file wherever the file is,right?Can anyone give me some advice?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The path works if you use single quote marks rather than double quote marks (at least when I test it your code doesn't work with the double quotes and does with single quotes).

```
import xlwings
workbook=xlwings.Book('C:\\Users\\[username]\\Desktop\\test.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheets['Sheet1']
sheet.cells(1, 1).value=1
```

The above code runs without throwing an exception on my machine. (As does using a raw string instead of the double backslash)